# We did not have a holiday last year

Tags: imaginary-situations

> We did not have holiday last year

(source ......)

What is the meaning of this sentence i think it can be-(1) we did not receive holiday last year or (2)we did not spend a holiday last year

Comment: What is the source of that sentence please.

Comment: I assume you mean "Raymond Murphy grammar",  (note the "y in Raymond, the "u" in Murphy, and the "ar" at the end of grammar).  Please go and check letter-by-letter that the quote has been done perfectly. I don't think Mr Murphy would write "We did not have holiday". You can then [edit] your post to add the source: see where it says "(source .....)  ***you*** need to edit that.  If you can give the book title and page number as well that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The article is effectively *required* (it should be *We did not have **a** holiday last year*, so you've probably copied it wrong). But I don't understand why you think it could mean *We **did** have a holiday last year, **but we didn't enjoy it***

Comment: Sorry i did a mistake you were right i left 'a'

Comment: _Holiday_ here is used in the British sense, equivalent to the American _vacation_. The speaker and their family did not go away on vacation. (It's _did not spend_, but you would only use the verb _spend_ when you mention the place you went to. _We spent our holiday in Brighton_.)

Comment: Raymond Murphy, Essential grammar in use, 2nd edition,page no-49

Comment: Thank you all of you for giving me such a precious time

Comment: Still having some confusion with the possession sense (Holiday here is used in the British sense, equivalent to the American vacation. The speaker and their family did not go away on vacation. (It's did not spend, but you would only use the verb spend when you mention the place you went to. We spent our holiday in Brighton.) – Kate Bunting 13 sion with the possession sense)

Comment: "We did not have **a** holiday" might mean either "We had no time off work" or "We did not go away". 'Spend' is not used as you used it. Examples: We spent our holiday in Brighton / at home / by the sea / on a boat OR We spent our holiday cycling / sleeping / making cakes / building sandcastles.

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] your question to include the clarifications requested: is the quote "...did not have holiday..." or "...did not have a holiday...", and what is the source?

Answer (score 1):

English is my native language.

Your sentence is saying that the subjects of the sentence 'we' didn't go on holiday last year.

Comment: We did not have a holiday" might mean either "We had no time off work" or "We did not go away". 'Spend' is not used as you used it. Examples: We spent our holiday in Brighton / at home / by the sea / on a boat OR We spent our holiday cycling / sleeping / making cakes / building sandcastles. – Old Brixtonian